# Need help writing a script to enable all the lazy loaded images after the DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VePvK.png) So my website's home page has about 145 requests and about 60% of the requests are images so i'm trying to reduce the DOM Content Load time by adding the loading="lazy" tag to all the img tags in my homepage. But once the DOM Content is loaded, I want the rest of the images to load so I want lazy tag removed.

I tried writing a script such that once the Dom content is loaded, find all the texts that says "lazy" and remove it. here's the code

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    var lazyloadImages;
    lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("lazy");
    var imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
          var image = entry.target;
          image.src = image.dataset.src;
          image.classList.remove("lazy");
          imageObserver.unobserve(image);
    });
   });
  });
```

The lazyloadImage variable returns null, I don't know whats wrong. I would like for a solution here or any other better approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of your idea looks correct. Although you are missing the `options` of the `IntersectionObserver`.

To answer your question, you are looking for DOM elements having the `loading` attribute contains the value `lazy`, you are now looking for `lazy` DOM elements.

This should fix your problem (including a limitation to `img` elements)

```js
lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img[loading='lazy']");
```

To answer your other question, if there is a better approach. That all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Do you want/need to remove the `loading` attribute? Maybe you want to remove the image from the DOM once you've scrolled down a lot (like a timeline), and reload it when the image will (almost) get into the viewport again. We don't know your use-case.

[update]
In case you want to remove the loading attribute, you need to remove the attribute from the data instead of the classlist.

```
image.dataset.remove("loading");
```

However, it will not prevent the function again, because the IntersectionObserver already is bound to the DOM elements.

Instead you might want to verify if the src attribute must be set.

```js
//...
if (image.src === image.dataset.src ){ 
   return;
}
image.src = image.dataset.src;
//...
```

No need to remove the the `loading` attribute (at least no technical reason to remove it). And no need to `unobserve` the dom element.

But it all depends on your use-case. To give you an example:

If you would have a timeline of images where you have infinite scroll enabled, you most definitely would want to remove the images from the DOM too once they are out of your viewport, because it will otherwise explode your memory usage over time.

Comment: I want to reduce the DOM load time so I'm adding the loading="lazy" to all the image attributes but once the DOM is loaded, I want rest of the images 100px below the screen to load.... I used the code you gave me and now I can see the images in the lazyloadImages array... should i replace the "lazy" inside the remove tag as well?

Comment: In short, you need to remove the loading attribute from the dataset instead. I've updated my answer for more details.